# ¿Como renderizar el contenido de una variable en la vista?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Tengo una variable como la siguiente en un controlador de `angular`:

```
$scope.dato = "<h1>MI TITULO</h1>";
```

Quiero que se muestre en el `html`, pero renderizado... algo así como lo siguiente:

## MI TITULO

En la vista pongo así: `{{dato}}`, pero lo que muestra es el valor con los tag `html`

Comment: Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te fue de utilidad. Esto te dará reputación y ayudará a saber a los que responden que su ayuda fue bien recibida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final logre solucionar el problema.
La pregunta la han hecho en varias partes pero en ingles.
Di con la solución con respuestas a esas preguntas y principalmente con [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888822/parse-html-inside-ng-bind-using-angularjs) en la segunda respuesta.

Utilice ng-bind-html en la vista, $sce.trustAsHtml en el controlador, incluí la librería angular-sanitize.js y en el modulo agregue ngSanitize.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que sucede es que le estás pasando todo lo que va renderizar como cadena de texto, por eso ignora la estructura semántica de HTML.

Lo que debes hacer es, en tu HTML utilizar esa variable dentro de la etiqueta `h1`

Ejemplo:

HTML

```
<h1>{{dato}}</h1>
```

Mientras que en tu JS:

```
$scope.dato = "Mi título";
```

¡Saludos!

Comment: Te entiendo pero lo que quiero es que la variable tenga los tag html y después se muestre. Con php se puede hacer, javascript o Angular ya es otro cuento.

Answer (score 0):

Marck Vit. No uses el ng-bind-html. Es una muy mala práctica, además expones tu app para ataques al poder inyectar código. Está disponible, pero para usar en casos muy obligatorios. Una etiqueta H1 es una tontería.

Comment: Tendré muy en cuenta lo del ataque.
Solo puse como ejemplo lo de la etiqueta H1 para que me entendieran, pero necesito el ng-bind-html para poder crear un menú dinámico que me llega desde un Web Service. Por ahí vi un ejemplo donde lo hacen así para armar un componente dinámico. Gracias por tu aporte @darcusfenix